# Machine-translate a node by menu link

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have an "About us" *main-navigation* menu link.

I want to create several other *main-navigation* menu links, in languages other than English, which will link to that very webpage, for example:

- **เกี่ยวกับเรา** (about us in Thai)

  - If the user clicked that link, the destination would be the same "About us" webpage, but the content would be machine-translated to Thai.

---

The English content of "About us" is generally small (up to 1000 characters), well formatted, accessible and names and slang are avoided (unless some [escaping](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/content-translation/overview) is utilized).

---

I didn't find data about "machine" or "auto(matic)" in the *Content Translation* module documentation<sup>[1](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/content-translation/overview),[2](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multilingual/translating-content)</sup> but it might be worth to still ask if there any way inside Drupal itself to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal core (a standard Drupal install) does not have support for machine translation out-of-the-box.

However, you can add it easily by installing a contributed module.

[TMGMT](https://www.drupal.org/project/tmgmt) is a reliable module that will enable you to do machine translation with the following services:

- Google Translate
- Microsoft Translator
- Deepl

If you later decide to have professionals translate the site, TMGMT will support that too, which makes it better in my opinion than a module that only does machine translation.

Comment: It was written in the module's page `All Drupal text elements can be used as source for translation: Nodes Entities I18n Strings (Menu, Terms etc.)`, but does that includes translating by menu link?

Comment: @Alkalix Yes, the text you are quoting even says it supports menus ;)

Comment: yes, it just clear to me if that is the meaning in "supports menus" or something else (such as automatic translation of menu links under some browser state, instead of what I personally meant --- translating a node by menu link access).

Comment: it just wasn't*